# jqGrid: table headers width auto

Tags: jqgrid

I use jqGrid and I have some problem with header.
**Can I use table headers width, which depended from text length of each header?**

TIA.

Comment: can you be a bit more clear about your requirement

Comment: hm... I hane text in header: "Very short text". May width of head column set auto by width of this text?